# How to add OTP/Captcha for login in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to add OTP by sms/captcha for login authentication in rails app...

Organization ID, Registered Email, Password:
System Special Key:   == >  Submit Button.  Then Display field for OTP
OTP By SMS:,Captcha:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These links [reCAPTCHA and Rails](http://richonrails.com/articles/recaptcha-and-rails) and [recaptcha](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/) will help you to add captcha to your App.

You can use [active_model_otp](https://github.com/heapsource/active_model_otp) to implement One Time Password (OTP) feature in your rails App

Answer (score 1):

**add the gem--[RECAPTCHA](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/)**

```
 gem "recaptcha", :require => "recaptcha/rails"
```

Then register for a [reCAPTCHA API key](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list) and add that to your environment config files:

```
1 #put this in development.rb and in production.rb (separate keys in each so you can test!)
2 RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY= 'your-public-key'
3 RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY= 'your-private-key'
```

**AND Add following to config file**

```
 #in config/initializers/recaptcha.rb
 Recaptcha.configure do |config|
   config.public_key  = RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY
   config.private_key = RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY
 end
```

**use captch in view**

```
<%= raw recaptcha_tags %>
```

**at the controller level..The Captcha Gem provides another helper method that posts to the reCaptcha API server to check if what was submitted is correct**

```
##replace model.save with this

if @model.save ....

if verify_recaptcha(:model => @model, :message => "Please enter the correct captcha!") && @model.save
```

**IF YOU WANT TO USE CAPTCHA WITH devise,Visit [HERE](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise)**

Answer (score 1):

The most common and accessible one-time password (OTP) is SMS or voice-based since both SMS and voice, by default, are available on even the earliest generation of mobile phones. This makes SMS/voice OTP ideal if you are developing some service that targets people in all walks of life in every country in the world.

To send SMS/voice OTP you need send a request to an SMS/voice gateway, which sits between internet and phone infrastructure.

Unfortunately all SMS/voice gateway are owned by paid services, thus there is no such thing as open-source, that I can recommend. Fortunately, we found RingCaptcha (https://ringcaptcha.com), which has a the 'starter plan' that offers free 500 OTP monthly. Just a small plug for them for providing freemium service; they are highly reliable because they are integrated with all major global, and regional providers, e.g., Twilio, Nexmo, Infobip, MessageBird, etc., and send your OTP through the best provider/route based on country/phone carrier, and can auto fallback to alternative paths. This means you just need to integrate with RingCaptcha, without the headache of deciding which SMS/voice OTP provider has best combination of price and reliability, which is a real headache when you are sending OTP world-wide.

They have an easy to follow step-by-step tutorial which takes around 2-3 minutes to implement OTP for login: https://coderwall.com/p/x3zczq/rails-devise-alternative-password-less-database-less-user-sign-in-sign-up-using-2fa-in-2-minutes

It is based on a gem 'user_management_rails'.

I'll summarize the steps here:

- Make Rails app

  - `$ rails new YOUR_APP_NAME`
- Install user_management_rails gem

  - Add to 'Gemfile': `gem 'user_management_rails'`
- bundle install
- Register with RingCaptcha here: https://my.ringcaptcha.com/register
- Run generator to create sign-up, login, logout pages

  - `rails generate user_management_rails:install --ringcaptcha-key=YOUR_RINGCAPTCHA_APP_KEY --um-key=YOUR_UM_KEY`
- Launch Rails server

  - `rails server`
- Try!

  - `http://localhost:3000/`